# How to access variable from the variable

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have added a `Metafields Guru` app in my shopify store. I have created some metafields there And I want them to access in my template. All these are easily accessible if I access them individually. But problem is that how could I access if the key field come from another variable. I want code snippet something like below one.

```
{{product.metafields.productmeta.{block.settings.patitle | downcase }}}
```

`block.settings.patitle` comes from section block in a loop. And same downcased title is used as an key in metafields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture that string as something like a key:

```
{% capture mykey %}{{ block.settings.patitle | downcase }}{% endcapture %}
```

Then you can try accessing your metafield with that variable as in:

```
{{ product.metafields.productmeta.mykey }}
```

If that does not work, then why not try the string interpelation:

```
{{ product.metafields.productmeta['{{block.settings.patitle | downcase }}'] }}
```

Enough experimenting should get you what you want.

Comment: I did it already by experimenting same thing. Btw your answer is correct. Thanks